# Adding a listener to to leftBarButtonItem

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have a UIViewController that wants to execute some code when it is dismissed via the leftBarButtonItem (and popped from the stack to return to the parent view controller). This view has subviews of its own so I cannot just use viewWillDisappear.

What is the best way for me to call a custom method when the user presses the left bar button to return to the superview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even with subviews you should be able to use `viewWillDisappear`.

If you need specific actions to be taken on the subviews, run through them in `viewWillDisappear` as well.

If for some reason you **must** detect taps on the left bar button item your best bet is to overlay the actual `UINavigationBar` for that `UIViewController` with a lookalike `UIImageView` and implement a custom lookalike "back" button on the left side (standard UIButton).

Link the custom button to an IBAction and then perform whatever actions you need in there followed by

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: The thing is my view disappears when its subview loads, not just when it returns to its superview, so viewWilDisappear is out. That custom stuff sounds a little unfortunate. Maybe I should be going a different direction with this...

Comment: This definitely sounds like the whole approach could use some re-working but as a quick fix you could run checks within viewWillDisappear to check if it being popped or the subview is loaded. Further, you could switch to Storyboard and use the `- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender` method to customize for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

[Use Delegation, check out this code on Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/8924/ios4-alternatives-for-dismissviewcontrolleranimatedcompletion)